# Determine one real positive root of equation $16x^2+3-\frac{9}{x}=0,(x\neq 0)$ using the cutting method with precision up to $\epsilon =10^{-2}$.

Tags: numerical-methods

Determine one real positive root of equation $16x^2+3-\frac{9}{x}=0,(x\neq 0)$ using the secant method with precision up to $\epsilon =10^{-2}$.

What is the cutting method? Could someone show the procedure for solving this problem?

Note that I am not sure if this method is actually called "the cutting method". If someone knows how that method is called, please correct the name for it.

Comment: I think they mean bisection method with "cutting method". As in cutting an interval. Should be easy enough.

Comment: Maybe Newton-Raphson method?

Comment: This was posted by another user a few days ago as [Determine one real positive root of equation $16x^2+3-\frac{9}{x}=0,(x\neq 0)$ using the cutting method with precision up to $\epsilon =10^{-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290857/determine-one-real-positive-root-of-equation-16x23-frac9x-0-x-neq-0-u) (link only works for 10k+ rep users), then deleted minutes ago and now reposted under a different account. Fishy (-1).

Comment: Well, I guess it's the secant method (Latin "secare" - to cut), but this site is for answering questions, not for finding out what the question means. For all I know, "cutting method" is not a widely used terminology.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method), as a [secant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=secant) (from lat. *secare*, to cut) is a line that cuts a curve (in at least 2 points).

---

Another [translation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=bisect) could be the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), as that cuts intervals in two equal parts, see wikipedia or the search function here and on the web.

---

For the secant method choose two initial points $x_0,x_1$ and iterate
$$
x_{k+1}=\frac{x_{k-1}f(x_k)-x_kf(x_{k-1})}{f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})}
$$
until both $|x_k−x_{k-1}|<ϵ$ and $|x_{k+1}−x_k|<ϵ$. Then it is pretty sure that $x_k$ has precision $ϵ$, as
$$
|x_{k+1}−x_k|
=\left|\frac{f(x_k)}{\frac{f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})}{x_k-x_{k-1}}}\right|
$$ 
is by the first condition a close approximation to $\left|\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}\right|\approx |x_k-x_\infty|$.
$x_{k+1}$ will be even more precise.

As the function is monotonically increasing the choice of initial points should not matter much for the convergence of the method. The closer the initial points are to the root, the less steps it takes.

Comment: Could you give more details?

Comment: On what? Could you use your notes or scripts to find out what formula your "cutting method" uses? I do not think that you have to use a not introduced method that can also not be found in the recommended literature.

Comment: I don't if that "cutting method" is actually the secant method. Could you show the detailed procedure with the secant method?

Comment: This formula is already the procedure, you add a loop around it and a check on the size of the function value.

Comment: We can choose $x_0=10,x_1=5$, right? How to determine the number of iterations? What is the final solution? Is it $x_{k+1}$?

Comment: You compute the iterates until both $|x_{k+1}-x_k|<ϵ$ and  $|x_{k-1}-x_k|<ϵ$. Usually the last iterate computed is the best approximation.

Comment: And we can choose $x_0=10,x_1=5$, right?

Comment: Yes. As I wrote, any two different numbers will do as initial points.

Comment: And the final solution is $x_{k+1}$, right?

Comment: You seldom reach the exact solution with approximation methods, That is why the $ϵ$ was given.

Comment: So, until both $|x_{k+1}-x_k|<\epsilon$ and $|x_{k-1}-x_k|<\epsilon$? When we use the formula for $x_{k+1}$, and reach these conditions, the final solution is $x_{k+1}$, right?

Comment: Yes. Then it is pretty sure that $x_k$ has precision $ϵ$. $x_{k+1}$ will be even more precise.